# Report Generation with Multiple Filters Only Functioning on One Filter

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am attempting to build an expense database and report generator so my firm can view and track expenses over specified ranges and with these three filters: "employee", "client", and "category"(Expense category).  Everything is working except for when I attempt to use more than one filter.

If I use no filters so they're all ="" it works great.  If I use just the "employee" filter it works great, but if I try and use the employee filter with 2 other filters or 1 other filter it errors out that it can't find the start date or end date. Unsure what's going on.

```
Private Function GetReportInformationFromExpensesMaster(ByVal reportStartDate As Date, ByVal reportEndDate As Date, Optional ByVal employee As String, Optional ByVal client As String, Optional ByVal category As String) As Boolean
    'Generates report on reports master

    Dim transferDataRange As Range
    Dim startDateRow As Integer, endDateRow As Integer
    Dim errorMessage As String

    'employee filter
    If employee <> "" Then ExpenseMasterList.Range(ExpenseMasterList.Cells(2, MASTERLIST_EMPLOYEE_COLUMN), ExpenseMasterList.Cells(FindLastRow(ExpenseMasterList, MASTERLIST_EMPLOYEE_COLUMN), MASTERLIST_EMPLOYEE_COLUMN)).AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=employee, VisibleDropDown:=False

    'client filter
    If client <> "" Then ExpenseMasterList.Range(ExpenseMasterList.Cells(2, MASTERLIST_RELATED_CLIENT_COLUMN), ExpenseMasterList.Cells(FindLastRow(ExpenseMasterList, MASTERLIST_RELATED_CLIENT_COLUMN), MASTERLIST_RELATED_CLIENT_COLUMN)).AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=client, VisibleDropDown:=False

    'Category
    If category <> "" Then ExpenseMasterList.Range(ExpenseMasterList.Cells(2, MASTERLIST_CATEGORY_COLUMN), ExpenseMasterList.Cells(FindLastRow(ExpenseMasterList, MASTERLIST_CATEGORY_COLUMN), MASTERLIST_CATEGORY_COLUMN)).AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=category, VisibleDropDown:=False

    'Find rows after everything sorted
    startDateRow = FindDateRow(reportStartDate, True)
    endDateRow = FindDateRow(reportEndDate, False)

    If startDateRow = -1 Then

        errorMessage = "Start Date not found in Expense Master under these parameters"
        GetReportInformationFromExpensesMaster = True
        GoTo ErrorOutGetReport
        ExpenseMasterList.AutoFilterMode = False

    ElseIf endDateRow = -1 Then

        errorMessage = "End date not found in Expense Master under these parameters"
        GetReportInformationFromExpensesMaster = True
        GoTo ErrorOutGetReport
        ExpenseMasterList.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

    Set transferDataRange = ExpenseMasterList.Range(ExpenseMasterList.Cells(startDateRow, MASTERLIST_REF_ID_COLUMN), ExpenseMasterList.Cells(endDateRow, MASTERLIST_USD_AMOUNT_COLUMN))

    transferDataRange.Copy

    ReportSheet.Cells(9, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Clears autofilter mode on expense master list if necessary
    ExpenseMasterList.AutoFilterMode = False

    ReportSheet.Cells(8, 1).Activate

    Exit Function

ErrorOutGetReport:
    MsgBox (errorMessage)

End Function
```

**Find Start/End Rows by Date**

```
Public Function FindDateRow(ByVal dateToBeFound As Date, ByVal startDateBoolean As Boolean) As Integer
    'Finds date locations and if it is unable to find said date then it will return 0 to indicate that a suitable date was not found

    Dim finderRange As Range, masterListDateRange As Range
    Dim masterListLastRow As Integer, dateRowFound As Integer
    Dim dateLoopProxy As Date

    masterListLastRow = FindLastRow(ExpenseMasterList, MASTERLIST_DATE_COLUMN)

    Set masterListDateRange = ExpenseMasterList.Range("B3:B" & masterListLastRow)

    'Startdate or end date
    If startDateBoolean Then
        'StartDate

        Set finderRange = masterListDateRange.Find(dateToBeFound, after:=Cells(3, MASTERLIST_DATE_COLUMN), searchdirection:=xlNext)

        If finderRange Is Nothing Then
            'If date is not found iterate forward until it is found

            'Date proxy to test initial month against proxy month for iteration through the do loop
            dateLoopProxy = dateToBeFound

            Do Until Not finderRange Is Nothing Or Month(dateLoopProxy) <> Month(dateToBeFound)

                dateLoopProxy = dateLoopProxy + 1

                Set finderRange = masterListDateRange.Find(dateLoopProxy, after:=Cells(3, MASTERLIST_DATE_COLUMN), searchdirection:=xlNext)

            Loop

        End If

         If Not finderRange Is Nothing Then dateRowFound = finderRange.Row Else GoTo DateNotFound

    Else
        'End Date

        Set finderRange = masterListDateRange.Find(dateToBeFound, after:=Cells(masterListLastRow, MASTERLIST_DATE_COLUMN), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

        If finderRange Is Nothing Then
            'If date is not found iterate backwards until it is found

            'Date proxy to test initial month against proxy month for iteration through thedo loop
            dateLoopProxy = dateToBeFound

            Do Until Not finderRange Is Nothing Or Month(dateLoopProxy) <> Month(dateToBeFound)

                'Iterating backwards (up) to find end date
                dateLoopProxy = dateLoopProxy - 1

                Set finderRange = masterListDateRange.Find(dateLoopProxy, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

            Loop

        End If

        If Not finderRange Is Nothing Then dateRowFound = finderRange.Row Else GoTo DateNotFound

    End If

    FindDateRow = dateRowFound

    Exit Function

DateNotFound:
    FindDateRow = -1

End Function
```

Comment: Your question will get more attention if you present a simpler example of the problem you are trying to solve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I'm not entirely certain how to make it simpler.  The three filters are at the top of the first function in the post, which is very visible.  Just have 3 cells, which are either filled in and match values in each column of the database or they're blank and no filtering is required.